# WCF Ninject Ninject.ActivationException

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject

I get the error:

```
    Error activating IRule using binding from IRule to Crazy

A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.
```

I have multpiple rules is my "WCF service" the rules implements the interface IRule:

```
public interface IRule
{
    warior ExecuteRule(warrior _warrior);
}
```

for example the rule Crazy looks like this:

```
public class Crazy : IRule
    {
        private readonly IRule _rule;

        public Crazy(IRule rule)
        {
            _rule = rule;
        }

        public wariors ExecuteRule(warriors _warriors)
        {
            using (var context = new warriors_officialEntities())
            {
                _warriors = context.warriors.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == _warriors.Name);
                _warriors.cursed = (_warriors.Sleep > 70 && _warriors.Hunger > 70);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return _warriors;
        }
    }
```

I'm also using a ninject module I call it the RuleFactory.
I bind an IRule to every rule class and give them a name.

```
public class RuleFactory : NinjectModule
{

    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IRule>().To<Crazy>().Named("crazy");
        Bind<IRule>().To<Hungry>().Named("hunger");
        Bind<IRule>().To<Munchies>().Named("munchies");
        Bind<IRule>().To<Sleepy>().Named("sleepys");
    }
}
```

When I retrieve all the wariors from my service is fire a method called DoRules(), this method will loop trough all the warriors and tries to execute every rule for them.

```
 IKernel _rules = new StandardKernel(new RuleFactory());
 public void DoRule(List<warriors> tmgs)
        {
            IEnumerable<IRule> rules = _rules.GetAll<IRule>();
            using (var context = new warriors_officialEntities())
            {
                foreach (warriors tmg in tmgs)
                {
                    foreach (var rule in rules)
                    {
                          rule.ExecuteRule(tmg);
                    }
                    tmg.LastAccess = DateTime.Now;

                    context.Entry(tmg).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

The code will give an exception in `foreach (var rule in rules)` Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Crazy` class' receives an `IRule` as constructor parameter - but doesn't use it. This causes a cyclical dependency - but I believe the relevant binding is missing from your question.

The exception occurs on `foreach (var rule in rules)` because `GetAll` returns an `IEnumerable` which only leads to actually retrieving the instances when it is enumerated. Hence the exception doesn't occur on `GetAll` but rather when looping the `IEnumerable`.

As the `Crazy` class doesn't actually make use of the `IRule` it get's injected just remove it from the constructor and the exception should go away.